# Vuetify: Changing navbar entirely at breakpoint

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm using nuxt and vuetify, and I have a pretty normal default layout with a navbar added, as seen below:

```
<v-app dark>
 <v-app-bar height="60" max-height="60" app>
   <Navbar />
 </v-app-bar>
...
<v-app />
```

With `Navbar` being a custom component. However I need to swap out the current component (as in, totally change the grid-based layout to the point that adding a few breakpoints for justify and align content and whatnot would not suffice) for another one, containing most of the components of the first Navbar, just with a different layout.

What would be the most efficient method for swapping out the two different layouts/components at different screen sizes?

I was thinking of using `vue-mq` but I was wondering if there were better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on something similar using `$vuetify.breakpoint`. Depending on when you want to swap out the component you can play around with the following method as a computed property.

```
        isMini() {
            switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
                case 'xs': return true
                case 'sm': return true
                case 'md': return true
                case 'lg': return false
                case 'xl': return false
                default: return false
            }
        }
```

You can then use the computed property value to conditionally render your components:

```
        <!-- NavBar 1 -->
        <nav v-if="isMini" class="navbar">
             ...
        </nav>
        <!-- NavBar 2 -->
        <nav v-else class="navbar">
             ...
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify provides breakpoints by default which you can access through `this.$vuetify.breakpoint` inside your Vue components. Creating a computed prop that is pointing to the breakpoint props and conditionally rendering `NavBar` or another component depending on the computed prop could be the way.

More information about [Vuetify Breakpoint Service Object](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service-object)